# why do I get different dimension on my menu in html when I use a script to implement it

Tags: html, menu, dimensions

First my original code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu1.css">
</head>

<div id=menu>
       <ul>     <!-- below is the classic vertical menu -->
                <li><a class="home" href="home.asp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="news" href="news.asp">News</a></li>
                <li><a class="shop" href="shop.asp">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a class="journey" href="about.asp">Our journey</a></li>
                <li><a class="contact" href="contact">Contact</a></li>
                <!-- search element-->
              <!--  <input type="text" placeholder="Typuhhhh"> -->
        </ul>
     </div>
</html>
```

But I want it external so I can change it once for every page so I did the following;

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu1.css">
</head>

<div id="menu">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>$("#menu").html('<object data="menubaperium.html">');</script>
</div>​



</html>
```

and to be complete the "menubaperium.html

```
<head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu1.css">
    </head>

    <div id=menu>
       <ul>     <!-- below is the classic vertical menu -->
                <li><a class="home" href="home.asp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="news" href="news.asp">News</a></li>
                <li><a class="shop" href="shop.asp">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a class="journey" href="about.asp">Our journey</a></li>
                <li><a class="contact" href="contact">Contact</a></li>
                <!-- search element-->
              <!--  <input type="text" placeholder="Typuhhhh"> -->
        </ul>
     </div>
```

But when I use the script version my menu in not horizontally lined out I searched the internet but I can not find a solution. I hope someone can help me..

Comment: try with `<script>document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = '<object data="menubaperium.html">';</script>`

Comment: Hi Vepthy, thnx for the quick response, I have tried your suggestion but unfortunately it does not work it is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after days of searching the internet and trying I found a working solution.
First I changed this part;

```
 <div id=menu>
   <ul>     <!-- below is the classic vertical menu -->
            <li><a class="home" href="home.asp">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="news" href="news.asp">News</a></li>
            <li><a class="shop" href="shop.asp">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a class="journey" href="about.asp">Our journey</a
            </li>
            <li><a class="contact" href="contact">Contact</a></li>
            <!-- search element-->
          <!--  <input type="text" placeholder="Typuhhhh"> -->
    </ul>
 </div>
```

For this part;

```
  <body>
    <nav id="navMenu"></nav>
    <script src="menu.js"></script>
  </body>
```

and to be complete the menu.js;

```
 document.getElementById("navMenu").innerHTML =
  '<ul>'+
  '<li><a href=>"home.asp">Home</a></li>'+
  '<li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>'+
  '<li><a href="shop.asp">Shop</a></li>'+
  '<li><a href="about.asp">Our journey</a></li>'+
  '<li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>'+
 '</ul>';
```

Hopefully this will help someone with the same problem.